# Flutter Firestore: Is there way to get another collection's documents based on another collection's documents?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 collections in Firestore, Subscribed & Lists. I want to firstly filter the documents from the first collection(Subscribed) to get only the documents that the user has subscribed to, so something like

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("subscribed").where("userId", isEqualTo: currentUser.uid).where("subscribed", isEqualTo: true).snapshots();
```

Now once I get the documentID from the snapshot, I want to use those ids to iterate over those particular lists and display them

What I have tried is

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: getSharedListsStreamSnapshot(context),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return SpinKitDoubleBounce(color: Colors.black);
              else
              return new ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.lenght,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                      buildHomeViewCard2(context, snapshot.data.docs[index]));
            }),

Stream<QuerySnapshot> getSharedListsStreamSnapshot(
      BuildContext context) async* {
    final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("subscribed")
        .where("userId", isEqualTo: uid)
        .where("subscribed", isEqualTo: true)
        .get()
        .then((val) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("subscribed")
          .where("userId", isEqualTo: uid)
          .where("subscribed", isEqualTo: true)
          .get()
          .then((event) {
        event.docs.forEach((element) {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("lists")
              .where("id", isEqualTo: element['listId'])
              .snapshots();
          print(element['listId']);
        });
      });
    });
 Widget buildHomeViewCard2(
      BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    final lists = Lists.fromSnapshot(documentSnapshot);
    final listIcon = lists.iconForList();
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: (listIcon.containsKey(lists.icon))
                ? listIcon[lists.icon]
                : listIcon["list"],
            title: Text(
              lists.name,
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => TasksView(
                  lists: list,
                ),
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
 }
```

It prints the element['listId'] but it doesn't show any lists on the ui.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what this part of your code ` Lists.fromSnapshot(documentSnapshot);` is doing when trying to print the info. You mention that the `element['listId']` is correctly printing the information. In order to print the data from the documentSnapshot notice that you need to use the `data()` method as it is explained on the [relevant documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#documentsnapshot). I hope it helps!

Comment: @DanielOcando Thanks. So when I was trying with breakpoints, my program crashes at the very first .get() in the getSharedListsStreamSnapshot method and throws an error "The getter 'docs' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: docs"

Comment: @DanielOcando I get back a list of IDs as asked for but I can't use those ids to access the documents in another collection in either a where clause or by specifying the docID

Comment: hi @RitikaDesai , I don't understand what do you mean by `I can't use those ids to access the documents in another collection in either a where clause or by specifying the docID `. what do you mean by this and where do you want to use these data in your code snippet?